# Get file stream without load it into memory

Tags: c#, .net, stream

How is it possible to get the file that the user is uploading without load it into memory?
This row make the memory go up  `var request = await httpContent.ReadAsMultipartAsync()`;

The client can only upload one file so is there a way to get the stream without go trough ReadAsMultipartAsync?

```
var request = await httpContent.ReadAsMultipartAsync();
var content = request.Contents.FirstOrDefault();
var stream = await content.ReadAsStreamAsync();
```

I only want the stream of the content. If I get the stream like this:

```
var stream = await httpContent.ReadAsStreamAsync();
```

Then it give a file that looks like this:

-----------------------------224143682423505141523038143258
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="file"; filename="test.txt"
Content-Type: text/plain

my dummy content

-----------------------------224143682423505141523038143258--

Answer (score 0):

Uploading file to an asp.net webservice always bloats the memory because that's the way your request pipeline works. There is an alternative though, when you are using a cloud service for example. In that case you can use the valet key pattern to upload a file immediately to a storage solution. This prevents your service from having to deal with the payload.

If you do want your service to handle the request, there's no way of doing to without consuming memory.